# Is there a way to skip Form Auth for intranet access?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm running a mvc web application with Form Authentication in my company.

For convenience reason, I want to allow people in the same intranet to access this web app without login.

Is there a way to skip the login page based on the UserHostAddress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` for this purpose:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (IsIntranetAddress(httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }

    private bool IsIntranetAddress(string ip)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then decorate the controllers/actions which would normally require authentication with this attribute:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @tk, yes, it is possible. You could do this in the action which serves as entry point to your application: check if it is an intranet user and if it is emit the authentication cookie for some specific UserID.

Comment: thnx, I accidently deleted my original comment, which is asking how to assign an arbitrary UserID to the intranet users.